# Calling a command from item collection in PRISM/ MEF/ WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism, mef

Suppose I have the following:

```
<Grid x:Name="root">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
             <DockPanel>
               <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.MyCommand}" />
               <!---There are other UI elements here -->
              </DockPanel/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

This code executes MyCommand when the button is clicked, but I also want to execute MyCommand when   the user presses Enter Key while the row is selected (which means button is not in focus)...

How to best do this in WPF/MEF/PRISM?

I recognize that in code I can't cast the DataContext to (MyViewModel) because that would violate MEF, and in code behind I only know the viewmodel interface type IViewModel...

```
//code behind of the XAML file above
public IViewModel ViewModel
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Note: I am thinking of doing this in code behind, but I'm not sure if the answer is even I should do it in the viewmodel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using KeyBindings. Create a new KeyBidnign to your Window and associate a Command to it. [More information on KeyBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<ListBox.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
</ListBox.InputBindings>
```

The CanExecute method of your viewmodel should have a validation for Selected Row.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(MyCommandExecute, MyCommandCanExecute);
    }

    private void MyCommandExecute()
    {
        // Do your logic
    }

    private bool MyCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return this.SelectedRow != null;
    }

    public object SelectedRow { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand MyCommand { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have other elements in my window, not just the listbox, where the user can actually press keys (that are valid scenarios). In your example, this means that inputbindings on the window will catch all Enter keys on the window right? What if I just want to catch those Enter keys in the row? (In my window actually there are many possible key interactions that's why I want to be specific as much as possible as to where I am catching events, but not only that, I am looking for the most appropriate solution for PRISM)